# SQL how to constraint check insert can only be letters and apostrophes?

Tags: sql

When I try to add an apostrophe to a `CHECK` constraint by using

```
column_name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z']%'
```

it just ends the text early in the second apostrophe.

How do I let the check accept apostrophes, letters and nothing else in the `varchar` insert?

Thank you

Edit for Context:  I used a random name generator and instead of taking out all the names with ' in them like "O'Neal" I've decided to allow them. so I need a way to make sure to only allow letters and apostrophes. Just allowing letters isn't enough and excluding just numbers still leaves [$% and other symbols

Comment: What dialect of SQL? What's your full code? What's the source data, desired output, current wrong output, and a description of the error?

Comment: its for names, i used a random name generator and instead of taking out all the names with ' in them like "O'Neal" I've decided to allow them. so I need a way to make sure to only allow letters and apostrophes. just letters isn't enough and excluding just numbers still leaves [$% and other symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a single quote in a string it needs to be doubled up

```
'%[^A-Z'']%'
```